# PendingIntents/AlarmManager isn't adding the delay but triggering the alarm immediately

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am struggling to get the pending intent/alarm manager to work properly. I believe I had it working properly but then I added some 'aar' files to libs and had to redo the gradle which seemed to have broken my base alarm.

```
 private void setAlarm(int hour, int min, Calendar cal, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hello, we made it for " + hour + min);
//        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Hello - timer after - " + cal.getTime());

        intent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

That is the snippet I am using to trigger the alarm. The intent is linked to another class which is triggering the alarm.

Comment: If you set alarm for past time then it will fire right away .Debug the calender instance .

Comment: use cal.add instead of cal.set.
Add:Adds the given amount to a Calendar field.

Comment: The parameter I am passing gets it from the calendar in a previous function. 
Also, the log right before the pending intent has the exact time I want the alarm at but triggers before that. So I don't think it's taking in a past time.

Comment: If the hour (today) is already past, then add one day.

Comment: I am not testing past time yet. All the issues I've had have been the same day and within the next 1-2 minutes for testing purposes.

Comment: `I am not testing past time ...` you actually **should**. That was my suggestion. Keep in mind that since API Level 19 the AlarmManager is no longer accurate. Sometimes it can fail for several minutes. Try using `setExact()`, insetad of `set()`. From the official docs: `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).`

Comment: @NoiseGenerator setExact fixed it!! Thank you. That explains why it was working at times and then suddenly not the next day.

I am now looking into incrementing the day if it has passed already. Eventually I'd like to set it up for the week but I'm still learning so I should take it little by little.

Comment: Managed to add a day if the time already happened today. Simple 'if' statement.

Comment: Exactly what I was suggesting you to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following code.

```
private void setAlarm(int hour, int min, Calendar cal, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hello, we made it for " + hour + min);
//        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Hello - timer after - " + cal.getTime());

        intent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (hour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (min * 60 * 1000) , pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: The hour, min parameters have the raw time, not the delay. So for example, if it's 1:00am and I set an alarm for 1:30am, that would make it 2:30am.

Comment: Can you check now i have edited the code. I think you must add System.currentTimeMillis() to your calender time if you are using set and not add.

Comment: The sum of the two ends up being some undefined time. :(

Comment: Try setting this directly and see if this works 
 System.currentTimeMillis() + (hour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (min * 60 * 1000)

Comment: No luck with that either.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator 's suggestion fixed it. I needed to use setExact with the alarm manager.